# How to delete user account from firebase with angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have some users and this user has roles , lawyers can delete clients and admins can delete lawyers and clients , but when i am logged in as admin i can delete another user because i can get idToken of another user because to get the idToken i need to login with this user  and i am logged in with my admin user and i only have my idToken no the token of the another user.
can anyone help me ?

i try this :

```
  borrarUsario(usuario:UsuarioModel)
    {


      this.http.delete(`${this.url}/Usuarios/${usuario.FireBaseID}.json`).subscribe();
      return this.http.post(`https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:delete?key=${myKey}`,{"idToken":`${usuaro.FireBaseID}`});


    }
```

but this response with error idToken Invalid because the idToken is not the Firebase ID  , how can i get the idToken witouth login with the another user

Answer (score 0):

The [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) provides the tools needed for [User Management](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users).

One option would be to leverage [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) to run the Admin SDK, for example, using [HTTP tiggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).

Or use the Admin SDK on your server. The following languages are supported out of the box:

- JavaScript (Node.js)
- Java
- Python
- Go
- C#

## Delete User using Node.js

```
admin.auth().deleteUser(uid)
  .then(function() {
    console.log('Successfully deleted user');
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error deleting user:', error);
  });
```

See [**Manage Users: Delete a user**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user)

See: [`deleteUser`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth.html#deleteuser)